# How to avoid copying large pieces of code in a program

Tags: c++

I have written a program that contains 3 functions. Each function contains the same 50 lines (or so) of code and although the program works it seems unnecessarily long. I'm trying to find a way of writing it more compactly so that this large chunk doesn't have to be copied 3 times.

I'm using c++ but I'm fairly new. Thanks in advance!

The code is in the following form:

```
#include etc
using namespace std

int u=0;
k_y = 1.0E-6;
for (k_x=(1.0E-6); k_x<(pi/a); k_x+= stepsize)

    { (here is a big block of code labeling the elements of a 6x6 matrix)

    }



k_x = pi/a;
for (k_y=(0.0); k_y<(pi/a); k_y+= stepsize)

    { (here is the same block of code)
    }

k_y=pi/a;

for (k_x=(pi/a); k_x>(0.0); k_x-= stepsize)

{
 (the same block of code again)
}
```

Comment: pls add the code or we can't help you.

Comment: Just factor out the duplicated code into a new function. If you post some code we can give concrete advice.

Comment: I'm having some trouble formatting the code on here and its quite long but i'll write out the general format that i mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should factor the duplicated code out into its own function:

```
void labelMatrix (MatrixType& matrix /*any other things you need*/)
{
    //code to label elements
}

//now in some function scope
int u=0;
k_y = 1.0E-6;
for (k_x=(1.0E-6); k_x<(pi/a); k_x+= stepsize)
{ 
    labelMatrix(my_matrix);
}

k_x = pi/a;
for (k_y=(0.0); k_y<(pi/a); k_y+= stepsize)
{
    labelMatrix(my_matrix);
}

k_y=pi/a;
for (k_x=(pi/a); k_x>(0.0); k_x-= stepsize)
{
    labelMatrix(my_matrix);
}
```